# Office Interop constructor with arguments

Tags: c#, com, office-interop

I am trying to compile someone else's project.  They wrote code that looks like this:

```
var doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document(pathToFile);
```

I can compile it fine in Visual Studio 2010 (where it was developed), but when I compile the same project in Visual Studio 2015, it gives this error:

```
'Document' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

In this case, Document is an interface:

```
[Guid("0002096B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[CoClass(typeof(DocumentClass))]
public interface Document : _Document, DocumentEvents2_Event { }
```

And the CoClass looks like this:

```
[ComSourceInterfaces("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentEvents2")]
[Guid("00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[TypeLibType(2), ClassInterface(0)]
public class DocumentClass : _Document, Document, DocumentEvents2_Event, DocumentEvents_Event
{
    public DocumentClass();
    [DispId(-2147418112)] public virtual string _CodeName { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The definitions looks identical in the metadata view from both versions of Visual Studio, and both are loading the interop file from:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
```

In neither case does DocumentClass contain a non-default constructor, but it compiles in Visual Studio 2010.

Why does it compile in 2010?  And given that it does compile in 2010, why doesn't it compile anymore in 2015?

And how can I discover the equivalent invocation for Visual Studio 2015 to make it work?

Comment: +1 for the question. I am interested to hear the answer. Are you sure it is using the exact same interop assembly?

Comment: Yes, they're both using 15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c from the GAC.

Comment: I repro'd in VS 2010.  Strange...

Comment: Long shot - but if it's not too convoluted or big, then porting to the OpenXML SDK may save you some pain now and down the road too. https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXMLSDK-MOT/

Comment: What's odd is that you can even call a constructor on an interface, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Possibly something that the Roslyn compiler cracked down on @roryap. Bryce, have you tried converting to Application application = new Application();
 Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

Comment: @roryap In COM, you can call constructors on interfaces which have a "CoClass" attribute.  The CoClass points at "DocumentClass", and it should be using the constructor from there.

Comment: I called it like this in VS2010, and ran with no problems:  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);`

Comment: @roryap OK, based on your test with random data, I'm guessing the constructor arguments are doing nothing in 2010, and 2015 actually complains about the invalid arguments.

Comment: @BryceWagner but wouldn't there have to be a constructor on `DocumentClass` that accepted a paramarray of `object` or something for that to work?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a bug in the 2010 compiler.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft It's not my code to maintain, I'm just trying to set up automated builds, and the build server is using a different compiler than the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @roryap test in the comments, it looks like Visual Studio 2010 was allowing invalid calls to the COM interop constructor.

I compiled the code in Visual Studio 2010 and used ILSpy to see what it generated:

```
doc = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(
        new Guid("00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")));
```

The file path is nowhere to be seen.  Visual Studio 2015 must have fixed the bug, and it no longer ignores constructor arguments like it used to.